# Where did my numbers go when adding index to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My integers become NaNs when I add the index to the DataFrame.

I run this:

```
newRows = {'guavas':  [10, 20], 
           'pears':   [111,222], 
           'avocados':[200,3000]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newRows)
print (newDF)
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newDF, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
newDF.index.name = 'Store'
print(newDF)
```

and I get this:

```
   guavas  pears  avocados
0      10    111       200
1      20    222      3000
           guavas  pears  avocados
Store                             
Thriftway     NaN    NaN       NaN
Meijer        NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "old" `newDF` has index `[0, 1]` while the "new" `newDF` has index `['Thriftway', 'Meijer']`. When using the `DataFrame`-constructor with a DataFrame, i.e. `pd.DataFrame(newDF, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])`, pandas internally does a reindex with the list in the index-argument on the index of `newDF`.

Values in the new index that do not have corresponding records in the DataFrame are assigned `NaN`. The index `[0, 1]` and the index `['Thriftway', 'Meijer']` have no overlapping values thus result is a DataFrame with `NaN` as values.

To appreciate this try running the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
newRows = {'guavas':  [10, 20], 
           'pears':   [111,222], 
           'avocados':[200,3000]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newRows)
print (newDF)
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newDF, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer', 0, 1])
newDF.index.name = 'Store'
print(newDF)
```

and notice that the new DataFrame now contains the old data. To achieve what you want you can instead [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the existing DataFrame with the new index like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
newRows = {'guavas':  [10, 20], 
           'pears':   [111,222], 
           'avocados':[200,3000]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newRows)
print(newDF)
newDF = newDF.reindex(['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
newDF.index.name = 'Store'
```

You can even reproduce what pandas is doing internally by using the `index`-argument of `reindex`:

```py
newDF.reindex(index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
```

The result is, as before, a DataFrame where labels that were not in the DataFrame before have been assigned NaN:

```
           guavas  pears  avocados
Thriftway     NaN    NaN       NaN
Meijer        NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newDF, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
```

In above line, you are passing both dataframe and index to `pd.DataFrame()`.

From the [source code of `pandas.DataFrame()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L394-L9475), I pick some related codes as following with assumption that `data` is a dataframe:

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        data=None,
        index: Optional[Axes] = None,
        columns: Optional[Axes] = None,
        dtype: Optional[Dtype] = None,
        copy: bool = False,
    ):

        if isinstance(data, BlockManager):
            if index is None and columns is None and dtype is None and copy is False:
                # GH#33357 fastpath
                NDFrame.__init__(self, data)
                return

            mgr = self._init_mgr(
                data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
            )
```

- If `index` is given, `pandas.DataFrame()` will create a dataframe with the same columns as the passed dataframe. Each cell is filled with `NaN`.
- If `index` is not given, it will create a dataframe as same as the passed dataframe including index, columns and data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to set the index in your dataframe to something else than 0,1. However,

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newDF, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
```

This will actually set your newDF from given index (['Thriftway', 'Meijer']) in newDF. And since (currently) you don't have any values for these two index values in newDF it will write the column values as NaN for these index values.

Two possible solutions for setting up your custom index can be like this:

1. you specify index when you create your dataframe

```
newRows = {'guavas':  [10, 20], 
           'pears':   [111,222], 
           'avocados':[200,3000]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newRows, index=['Thriftway', 'Meijer'])
newDF.index.name = 'Store'
print(newDF)
```

2. you use set_index after

```
newRows = {'guavas':  [10, 20], 
           'pears':   [111,222], 
           'avocados':[200,3000]}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newRows)
newDF = newDF.set_index(pd.Index(['Thriftway', 'Meijer']))
newDF.index.name = 'Store'
print(newDF)
```